# How to pass the entire data in databese to an array in node js (using mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to pass the entire data in databese to  an array in node js (using mongoose)

Comment: This information can be easily found on the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), and [should not require a question to be asked](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Answer (score 0):

`Model.find({})` should be your answer. It is an asynchronous function so use `async/await` or a callback.

e.g

```
await User.find({})

OUTPUT:
[
  {
    age: 0,
    _id: 62ae10acd37b5a38cfc089b7,
    name: 'john mclain',
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: '',
    tokens: [ [Object] ],
    createdAt: 2022-06-18T17:51:40.895Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-18T17:51:40.936Z,
    __v: 1
  },
  {
    age: 1,
    _id: 62ae10acd37b5a38cfc089b7,
    name: 'john mclain2',
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: '',
    tokens: [ [Object] ],
    createdAt: 2022-06-18T17:51:40.895Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-18T17:51:40.936Z,
    __v: 2
  }
]
```